# Can you add an additional "process" or customize the default ASP.NET Core Registration feature?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

To start things off, I'm not the Initial developer of this project, and I'm almost completely new to asp.net core and entity framework (Java and Spring before).

**Situation**

So my teammate created a project mostly based on [this guide by microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). It's as simple as using the default AspNetUser Identity System. So from what I understand, no need to create an endpoint for Registration and get the registration details and save them somewhere - AspNet handles it all.

*But the problem is now we have an additional "demand" for our project.*

There's this "parent" project that another team is working on. It has it's own User system. Now what we're asked to do is:

1. When registering for child project, provide username and password credentials that you also use for parent project login.
2. Only Register the user IF the username and password exists.
3. If the user exists, also save the employeeId provided by the parent project into a column in table AspNetUser.
4. When logging in child project, authenticate via the parent project instead. If user exists, it will return a token that we'll be using for requests. We'll be saving the token somewhere else (Planning to create a custom claims http filter thing)

Is there anyway AspNetCore provides to allow adding additional steps/processes in registration that'd allow us to first verify the user via the parent project login? Or are we better off just creating our own user system without using the default one provided by AspNetCore (yeah security concerns etc.)

Comment: I think you are asking for SSO (Single Sign On), google that first.

Comment: What version of aspnet core is it built in and do you have the razor pages or views for registration available in your solution?
if you do not have them visible (they are packaged and not visible to you) follow this guide to scaffold them out
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity

if you do you should be able to add custom data to your users using this guide 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data

the logic can be added to the register method to check for users existance in the parent system.